# Ghostscript expand trimbox (add bleed) when converting to jpeg

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I have the following command line setup to create a jpeg copy of each page of a pdf, cropping it down to the trim size. Actually i'm wanting the bleed size which is 3mm added to each edge of the trim box

```
-o newbitmap_%04d.jpg -sDEVICE=jpegcmyk -dJPEGQ=60 -r150 -dSimulateOverprint=false -dUseTrimBox original.pdf
```

Please could someone suggest how I can do this?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

In the current Ghostscript code, use -dUseBleedBox. See :

http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=694977

Comment: Cool thanks, this doesn't look like its in version 9.10 as this has been added after 9.10 release, so I guess I need to wait till the next version